# Replace contents of string dynamically in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a

```
String name = " abc_efg_the_xyz_24_Mar_2016.csv ";
```

I would like to replace `24_Mar_2016` with `"18_Jan_2016"`. So that the new string becomes:

```
"abc_efg_the_xyz_18_Jan_2016.csv"
```

How can I do it?

Also the problem is that the date part in the string name will always keep changing so I can't do pattern search and replace with new date.

Please help

Comment: Maybe you should substring the file like always take the X first char then add your new date.

`var actualFileName = "xxx_xxx_date.csv";  
 var tmp = actualFileName.substring(0,7); //not sure if it's like that 
 var final = tmp + "yournewDate" + ".csv";`

Comment: What do you mean with " will always keep changing ", will it always be on the last part of the file name or not ?

Comment: Do u hear about `regular expressions`? Although, in your case when you know a substring position from start or end of a string you can just replace it by indices.

Comment: I dont get your request. Of course you don't **have** to put your strings hardcoded into patterns. You can build a pattern from a string that you pulled to together at runtime.

Comment: And then, the other thing: what have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: In my case, I will be reading the string name from a file and replace it with a value which comes from another file. So I cant hardcode anything in my code. Finally , this is what I wront and its working for me for now.

Comment: In my case, I will be reading the string name from a file and replace it with a value which comes from another file. So I cant hardcode anything in my code. Finally , this is what I wrote and its working for me for now. String checkDate = "23_DEC_2016";
                    String separate = StringUtils.substringBefore(name, ".");
                    String inProcess = separate.substring(0,separate.length()-11);
                    String finalName = inProcess+checkDate+".csv";

Answer (score 3):

You're asking two things here. First question is answered by:

```
String name = " abc_efg_the_xyz_24_Mar_2016.csv ";
String olddate = "24_Mar_2016";
String newdate = "18_Jan_2016";

// use replaceAll() if there will be multiple occurences the date
String replaced = name.replace(olddate, newdate);
```

The second question requires a regular expression matching the date format used by your naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done using [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and `Matcher` to cut off the old date.

But I think you will create a new file anyway and then you will also know the prefix to use before the date. So IMHO there is no need to "change" an old file name...

Comment: Offtopic: thanks for your edit on that junit answer of mine. I further enhanced it, but I like your idea there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your date has the following convention all the time:  **dd_mmm_yyyy** and that the **name** of the file has **ONE** date only. You can use [`String.replaceAll(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or [`String.replaceFirst(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and regex to solve this problem. Read more about regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

```
String replaceDate = "12_Feb_2017";
String name = "abc_efg_the_xyz_24_Mar_2016.csv ";

name = name.replaceAll("\\d{2}_[a-zA-Z]{3}_\\d{4}", replaceDate);
```

Here is an [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/UpNYlH)

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways:

```
String name = " abc_efg_the_xyz_24_Mar_2016.csv ";
name = name.replace("24_Mar_2016", "18_Jan_2016");
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have always same date format and the location of the date string in your `name`, but the date value in your `name` could be different.

```
String name = "abc_efg_the_xyz_24_Mar_2016.csv";
System.out.println(name.replaceFirst(".{11}(?=[.][^.]+$)","Happy_NEW_YEAR"));
```

This will print:

```
abc_efg_the_xyz_Happy_NEW_YEAR.csv
```

- The `".{11}(?=[.][^.]+$)"` is regex, to match the 11 chars before the last period (`.`), in your case, it matches the date format xx_xxx_xxxx (length:11)
- the `replaceFirst` will only do substitution once. I didn't use pattern `\d{2}_\w{3}_\d{4}`, because I see you have other `abc_efg...` in your string, I am not sure if there could be the same matched pattern, which you don't want to replace.